# Redirecting an ASP.NET MVC user authenticated by IdentityServer3 to another ASP.NET MVC application without needing to login again

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, identityserver3

So I've set up an IdentityServer3 (let's call it IdSvr3). I have two ASP.NET MVC applications (mvc1 and mvc2) that both use IdSvr3 for authentication. So the user is authenticated for mvc1 and at some point I want to redirect the user to mvc2 without having the user login again. I asked the question on https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues and Brock Allen one of the two developers of the IdentityServer3 project responded as follows:

"You need to do the standard redirect to the token service. Since the user is already logged into IdentityServer, then they will not be prompted to login again."

But I don't know how to do it. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

Identity Server will act as Single Sign On for you.

If you authenticate mvc2 in the same way as mvc1, you will automatically be signed in.

If you are using the OpenId Connect OWIN library this will automatically redirect (302) to Identity Server for you, and if you are already signed in to Identity Server, it will not prompt you to login.